# Keeping two Sharepoint sites in sync

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint, wss

I have two Sharepoint sites in different countries. How can I make the data in the two sharepoint sites to be identical. When an item added to first site, I want it to appear in the second site. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

U can use SharePoint **Content Deployment** functionality to transfer content from one site to another.